# Unexpected in_array() behaviour

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have the following array:

```
$enabled = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'article' => 0,
);
```

Note "article" is a key, but not a value. Since `in_array()` searches for matching values, I would expect the following line to return FALSE:

```
in_array('article', $enabled)
```

Yet, it returns TRUE. Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `in_array()` by default performs a loose comparison and this causes PHP to evaluate the expression `(0 == "article")` as `TRUE`.

You need to use the strict parameter for `in_array()` to also check the types of the needle in the haystack:

```
var_dump( in_array('article', $enabled, true) );
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53337)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused why "article" would == 0, since I would assume it would == "1" if anything. Can you point to documentation which explains this? I appreciate the answer.

Comment: @JoelStein: Here you go: [php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the third parameter for strict type checking:

```
in_array('article', $enabled, true);
```

Otherwise, PHP will try to compare `0` (integer) and `'article'` (string).
→ `'article'` evalutes to 0!
→They're equal!

[Example @ codepad.org](http://codepad.org/qksDehs8)